# How do I put two texts that are of different font sizes at the center of a webpage? (vertically and horizontally centered)

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```css
span {
  font-family: 'Lovehearts XYZ';
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lovehearts XYZ';
  src: url('LoveheartsXYZ.woff2') format('woff2'), url('LoveheartsXYZ.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size: 70px;">Hi, I am *Name*</span>
</br>
<span style="font-size: 40px;">
    *Occupation*</br>
    *Hobbies*</br>
     *Facts about me*
</span>
```

As you can see, I use two "spans" but they have different font sizes. I want these two spans to be vertically and horizontally centered on the webpage.

Comment: `</br>` is invalid. It's `<br/>` or `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

span should have the following properties: dispaly: block, margin: auto;
span's parent should have: display: flex;

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all that into a `div` and center that using `display: flex: justify-content: center; align-items:center;` on the *parent*  of that DIV. And use `text-align: center` on that div itself.